# SQL selection of multiple tables

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

A database which stores currency conversion values. These values will be added to text boxes according to the input date in a vb.net program.

Given the three tables

```
GBP (table) 
Date (pk)
GUSD
GEUR

USD(table) 
Date (pk)
UGBP
UEUR

EUR(table) 
Date (pk)
EUSD
EGBP
```

How can i select all the records from all 3 tables excluding the Date?

I've managed to select records from one table.

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT TOP 1 GEUR,GUSD FROM GBPtb WHERE Date= ?"
```

[Design view of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRAaU.png)

Comment: Have one common table instead.

Comment: You could use [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limited information you provided, I'm guessing you might want something like the following

```
SELECT 1.0 as GBP, GUSD as USD, GEUR as EUR FROM GBP WHERE Date = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT UGBP as GBP, 1.0 as USD, UEUR as EUR FROM USD WHERE Date = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT EGBP as GBP, EUSD as USD, 1.0 as EUR FROM EUR WHERE Date = ?
```

Comment: Basically the program is suppose to display all the values in text boxes. What I want to do is fetch the values from the database (from all three tables) and display them. As for now i have a string to fetch the number I want. How can all this into a single string?

Comment: when the user selects the date, the program will fetch all the exchange rates from that date and display it. I uploaded a screenshot as well.